# Can you change Jupyter Lab text editor settings for a specific file type?

Tags: jupyter-lab

I'm looking at Jupyter Lab's **advanced settings editor** and added some rulers. But I don't want rulers to appear for a markdown file, and I want rulers to be different for Fortran file than python files. Is it possible to configure these settings for specific file types?

I have this...and it puts rulers on all files open in the text editor

```
{
    "editorConfig":{
        "rulers": [72,79,99],
        "lineWrap": "off"
    }
}
```

But I would like something like this...

```
{
"fortran":{
    "editorConfig":{
        "rulers": [1,7,79],
        "lineWrap": "off"
    }
}

"python":{
    "editorConfig":{
        "rulers": [4, 72,79,99],
        "lineWrap": "off"
    }
}

"markdown":{
    "editorConfig":{
        "rulers": [],
        "lineWrap": "on"
    }
}


}
```

Is it possible to set these advanced settings by file type?